# Extracting the currency and price value from a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to find a good way to extract a currency and price value from a string. It should work across multiple currencies. The parts…

- **Extracting the number** – could be an int or decimal value
- **Detecting a nearby currency symbol** to match it with a currency code
- **Ignore numbers that aren't prices** – e.g. not being *attached* to currency indicators

### Examples

- "Apples, 2x oranges and strawberries for 5.0 Euro"
- "Apples, 32 oranges and strawberries for 5.0 €"
- "Apples, oranges 5 € and strawberries"
- "Apples, oranges and strawberries for €5"

### Result

- Price as number: 5.0
- Currency code and symbol: € (EUR)

### Another example

- "Apples, 32 oranges and strawberries for $5.0"  → Number: 5.0, Currency US$ (USD)

What's a good way to approach this that works with different currencies?

Comment: FYI - The `$` symbol is used for a lot more than USD. A Canadian referring to Canadian dollars would just write something like "$5.00". Lots of other locales would also use `$` for their local currency.

Comment: True. For actual conversion I would probably combine the extracted information with the one from `[NSLocale currentLocale]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression for that. I use the following in my framework:

```
class Regex {
  private let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression
  let pattern: String
  var groups:[String]? = nil

  init(_ pattern: String) {
    self.pattern = pattern
    let regex: NSRegularExpression?
    do {
      regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      fatalError("Invalid pattern '\(pattern)` (\(error))")
    }
    internalExpression = regex!
  }

  init(_ pattern: String, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions) {
    self.pattern = pattern
    let regex: NSRegularExpression?
    do {
      regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: options)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      fatalError("Invalid pattern '\(pattern)` (\(error))")
    }
    internalExpression = regex!
  }

  func test(input: String) -> Bool {
    let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: [], range:NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult]
    if matches.count == 0 { groups = nil; return false }
    if internalExpression.numberOfCaptureGroups > 0 {
      groups = [String]()
      let match = matches[0] as NSTextCheckingResult
      for index in 1..<match.numberOfRanges {
        let range = match.rangeAtIndex(index)
        if range.location == 9223372036854775807 { groups!.append("") }
        else { groups!.append((input as NSString).substringWithRange(range)) }
      }
    }
    return true
  }

  func match(index:Int) -> String? {
    return groups![index]
  }
}
```

Then you can check for

```
let regexEuro = Regex("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?) *€")
let regexDollar = Regex("\\$ *(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)")
if regexEuro.test("This is 20 € ...") {
  print(regexEuro.match(0))
}
if regexDollar.test("This is $ 20.3 ...") {
  print(regexDollar.match(0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Regex framework above at Thomas post updated to Swift 4

```
class Regex {
    private let regex: NSRegularExpression
    let pattern: String
    var groups: [String] = []
    init(_ pattern: String, options: NSRegularExpression.Options = []) throws {
        self.pattern = pattern
        regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: options)
    }
    func contains(string: String) -> Bool {
        groups = []
        let matches = regex.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.utf16.count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult]
        guard !matches.isEmpty else {
            return false
        }
        if regex.numberOfCaptureGroups > 0,
        let firstMatch = matches.first {
            for index in 1..<firstMatch.numberOfRanges {
                let range = firstMatch.range(at: index)
                if range.location == .max {
                    groups.append("")
                } else {
                    groups.append((string as NSString).substring(with: range))
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    func match(index: Int) -> String? {
        return groups[index]
    }
}
```

---

```
let regexEuro = try! Regex("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?) *€")
let regexDollar = try! Regex("\\$ *(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)")
if regexEuro.contains(string: "This costs 20€"),
    let value = regexEuro.match(index: 0) {
    print("Euro value:", value)  // "20\n"
}

if regexDollar.contains(string: "This costs $20.3"),
    let value = regexDollar.match(index: 0) {
    print("Dolar value:", value)  // "20.3\n"
}
```